# What does Grub write to the boot sector for MBR boot?

Tags: mbr, grub2

Part of the syslinux [install process](https://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=HowTos) involves installing `mbr.bin` to the master boot record of a device.

```
dd \
  conv=notrunc \
  bs=440 \
  count=1 \
  if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin \
  of=/dev/sdX
```

If I restore those bytes from the disk, and compare them to the original `mbr.bin` file, they are identical.

```
$ sha512sum /usr/lib/syslinux/mbr/mbr.bin
3ba2bd96c7e5d81e...
$ dd bs=440 count=1 if=/dev/sdX | sha512sum
3ba2bd96c7e5d81e...
```

So far so good! Seems logical that those two checksums should be identical.

Grub seems a little more mysterious to me when I try to use it to accomplish the same behavior as Syslinux.

By doing a little sleuthing into `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` I can see that my `grub` install ends up calling this when it installs a new bootloader...

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc --force --no-floppy /dev/sdX
```

By running that same `grub-install` command and adding `--verbose`, I see that `grub-install` calls `grub-bios-setup`.

```
grub-bios-setup \
  --verbose \
  --force \
  --directory='/boot/grub/i386-pc' \
  --device-map='/boot/grub/device.map' \
  '/dev/sdX'
```

Looking at some of the [source](https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/d3fd939f18446b05d1d5456f23823498a1eb3fb4/util/setup.c#L154), I *think* that `grub-bios-setup` is what is responsible for writing to the MBR, because if I zero out the first 512 bytes then re-run `grub-bios-setup`, I see those bytes revert back to what they were before I zeroed them out.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the code well enough to totally understand **what** is being written by `grub-bios-setup`.

I had some hunches. I *think* part of what is written has to do with `boot.img`. Indeed, if I compare certain bytes from my boot sector and `boot.img`, they are the same (note, the total number of bytes read here is `440`).

```
$ skip=104 count=336; \
  sudo dd if=/boot/grub/i386-pc/boot.img \
    skip=$skip bs=1 count=$count 2>/dev/null | sha512sum ; \
sudo dd if=/dev/sdX \
    skip=$skip bs=1 count=$count 2>/dev/null | sha512sum

e531a81fd3eedb324a9...
e531a81fd3eedb324a9...
```

They have similarities, but they're not *entirely* the same. The first `104` bytes differ, and I can't understand what causes that difference.

Is there a comparable `mbr.bin` sort of file for Grub? Is it `boot.img`? Does Grub then modify some of those bytes? Is Grub generating those differing bytes on-the-fly? Are thoes bytes generated by Grub specific to each system, and unique every time Grub writes them?

Comment: I tried to look on my system to see what it uses, but... I switched to EFI a while back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `boot.img` is written to the first 440 bytes of the MBR. `boot.img` contains a "BIOS Parameter Block", which contains data that depends on the system it is installed on. This data is written to the BPM when Grub is installed. [Here](https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/master/grub-core/boot/i386/pc/boot.S) is the source code.

Btw, I wouldn't spend much time on GRUB. This code will probably not run on new PCs in a couple years. Intel is planning to get rid of legacy BIOS mode by 2020.

Comment: Thanks for that info! When you say "This data is written to the BPM when Grub is installed", do you mean that the BPB data is derived/written at the time when Grub is installed to the MBR? So running something like `grub-install` results in the system-specific BPB and the generic `boot.img` being combined in those 440 bytes in the MBR? Or do you mean that the BPB is written when the Grub binaries/package are installed on the host system?

Comment: And I know EFI is the modern/proper way of doing things now, but I didn't realize that legacy BIOS had a bit of a deadline. Good to know that 2020 date. Thanks!

Comment: When Grub is installed, the setup program reads `boot.img` into memory and pacthes it before writing it to disk as a new MBR. The data is coming from two different sources: the BPM and the partition table are read from the disk, and some are generated on-the-fly, like the boot drive (offset 0x64) and kernel_sector (offset 0x5c). Even two instruction bytes are changed to NOPs, if needed. The BPM is not present on the MBR, but the corresponding bytes are copied anyhow.

Comment: Intel announced the 2020 deadline at the end of 2017, but I wouldn't hold my breath. On the other hand, I see dumping the BIOS as a good thing in the long term, since the coexistence of both BIOS and UEFI is causing a lot of confusion.

Comment: December 2022, and still happily using grub installed in MBR and see no reason to change that in simple setups.